# Android Google Maps API

Tags: android, api, google, maps

Existe a possibilidade de traçar rota no `Google Maps` com informações sobre o trânsito, acidentes e tempo médio de chegada ao destino?
Ou alguma `lib` do tipo que faça esse tipo de requisição?

Comment: vou votar em fechar porque você fez várias perguntas numa só, existe sim solução para tudo o que perguntou, porém a resposta ficaria bem grande e muito complexa, da uma lida na documentação e a medida que for surgindo dúvidas específicas vai postando ai que vou explicando se eu souber ok. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir isso você vai precisar usar a **API de directions do google maps**.

Como a pergunta envolve muitas coisas recomendo que dê uma lida na documentação da API, que está em português.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=pt-br

Lá você vai encontrar o que precisa. Basicamente você vai fazer um request usando a origem e o destino, e vai receber um JSON com diversas informações, entre elas o tempo pra chegar no seu destino e os pontos de referência. Para exibir a rota você vai precisar criar uma **PolyLine** no seu mapa com os pontos de referência retornados no JSON.

Para exibir informações sobre o trânsito visualmente no mapa (a rua aparecer vermelha em caso de engarrafamento por exemplo) você não precisa utilizar a API de directions, basta utilizar a função **GoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true)** no seu respectivo mapa.